# localhost:3000 is defaulting to Welcome to Rails Page instead of the Radiant CMS site page

Tags: radiant

I am installing Radiant on Windows XP,   the database is the default sqlite3, server is Webrick (also tried on Mongrel), and Ruby/Rails files are installed onto WAMP.
The new site from the documentation 'example_application' is installed in c/wamp/www/ and the folder seems to be populated with all the necessary folders/files.

I'm assuming Rails is correctly installed because when I access localhost:3000/, I at least get the Welcome to Rails message. 
However, that means it's not loading the site page (should be the blank template?) when accessing localhost:3000.

I am going by these directions:
script/server -e production  - I ran this as the last step in the install

I go to http: in the browser window--
localhost:3000 - getting the Welcome to Rails Page
localhost:3000/admin - getting the below Error message
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/admin"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

-- I also tried binding Webrick to 127.0.0.1 -- didn't work (maybe this is a possible fix?)

**UPDATE:**
*I ran the rake routes and this is what it returned:
Invalid drive specification.
The system cannot find the path specified.
    admin_snippets GET
(partial log of the snippets)
Could not copy/paste from Aptana Studio.

* Update:
There's no index.html file in example_application/public so that should have taken care of the problem of the page defaulting to "Welcome to Rails!".  How do I set up a default route then to the Radiant admin login page as well as the blank site that should be loading at localhost:3000?

The routes.rb file says only this:
load File.join(RADIANT_ROOT, "config", "routes.rb")

---

*Also, I know that Rails is not meant for a Windows environment so please bear with me.  I apologize if there is already a logical fix somewhere/thread available for getting to the login page for Radiant.*

Thanks if anyone can advise.

ANSWER:

I finally got Radiant installed on Windows but I have no idea why I was having those problems earlier or why on this last try localhost:3000 worked.  This answer to my above question is for anyone in the future who is doing the install on Windows XP.

If you get up to the point from above, I tried 'thin start' as my last option which didn't work.  Then I tried rails server which I figured would default to Webrick.  However, localhost:3000 was not even loading at this point.
**Last attempt -- this WORKED -- script/server webrick**

**--- 'script/server webrick'**
loads incredibly slow and will show all the [Get] controller? info that was missing from the earlier attempts at loading localhost:3000.  The terminal should show a printout of the WelcomeController#index and info from sqlite3.

The Redirect URL from the terminal reads:
localhost:3000/admin/welcome -- this is where I found the login page

However, I am still missing the blank template page that should be loaded at localhost:3000
whereas the login page should be found separately at localhost:3000/admin instead of loading from both localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/admin/.

At this point, the dashboard should be up & running after you login.

Comment: Could you create a self-answer with the solution you found then mark as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unless you are actually developing (creating an extension, patching Radiant, ...), it is recommended to run as production. Not sure about windows, but usually you do `script/server -e production` for that.
- I assume the frontend redirects you to the backend, because Radiant has nothing to render. Try creating a Layout and a home Page first, quite sure that will render.